# GWT URL routing and other features

Tags: java, gwt

I am thinking about using GWT in my future project. I have few questions:

1. How can I define the structure of URLs? Does it allow me to recognize the parts of the URL by some information I have in database? How it is defined? Directly in Java or XML?
2. Does it support HTML5 history tools to change the URL without the necessity of using hashes?
3. Forms and editation of items in database - does it allow to generate Forms by definition and generate their validation, without the necessity of writing everything hard by hand?
4. Are there any tools for uploading files (images) in iframes, so that the page does not have to me reloaded? Drag'n'drop uploading? Are there any tools to simply manipulate uploaded images? Resize, crop...
5. Is it natively possible to create similar hover information like it can be seen on (for inst. when you hover an item on the left, there is an information bubble appearing on the right side):
   http://goout.cz/theatre/prague/
6. Is it natively possible to create similar search dialog like on the page http://goout.cz - for inst. when you type 'a' it starts to suggest items in the database with their pictures.
7. All the GWT application I've found, run in browser rather as an JS application - but is it possible for javascript disabled browser to use them? Can search engines go through them?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> 1. How can I define the structure of URLs? Does it allow me to recognize the parts of the URL by some information I have in database? How it is defined? Directly in Java or XML?

It's up to you to code it [all](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideCodingBasicsHistory.html) (or [almost all](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideMvpActivitiesAndPlaces.html#Places)) by hand, in Java.

> 2. Does it support HTML5 history tools to change the URL without the necessity of using hashes?

It's possible to do it ([quite easily](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/place/shared/PlaceHistoryHandler.Historian.html) actually) but GWT doesn't provide built-in support.

> 3. Forms and editation of items in database - does it allow to generate Forms by definition and generate their validation, without the necessity of writing everything hard by hand?

No. [Editors](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideUiEditors.html) cut the boilerplate by half, but you still have to build your forms by hand (but that's not a bad things: generated things never look or behave like you'd like to). And [UiBinder](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideUiBinder.html) helps creating UIs.

> 4. Are there any tools for uploading files (images) in iframes, so that the page does not have to me reloaded?

[Yes](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/FormPanel.html).

> Drag'n'drop uploading?

Not directly. There's support for [native drag-and-drop](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/event/dom/client/DropEvent.html), but not for accessing dropped files and uploading them. It's not hard to add though.

> Are there any tools to simply manipulate uploaded images? Resize, crop...

The [canvas API](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/index.html?com/google/gwt/canvas/dom/client/package-summary.html) is supported but you'd have to do it all "by hand" (including, particularly, getting the image to draw it to the canvas, and then upload the canvas content)

> 5. Is it natively possible to create similar hover information like it can be seen on (for inst. when you hover an item on the left, there is an information bubble appearing on the right side): http://goout.cz/theatre/prague/

Yes.

> 6. Is it natively possible to create similar search dialog like on the page http://goout.cz - for inst. when you type 'a' it starts to suggest items in the database with their pictures.

[Yes](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/SuggestBox.html).

> 7. All the GWT application I've found, run in browser rather as an JS application - but is it possible for javascript disabled browser to use them?

No.

> Can search engines go through them?

[Google can](http://code.google.com/web/ajaxcrawling/), with [little effort](http://code.google.com/p/gwt-platform/wiki/CrawlerSupport).

Comment: Is there any strong alternative, which allows generating the html even without Javascript? I need to generate a code, which will be strongly SEO. A tool, which generates Javascript, but does not require its use?

Comment: What you're looking for is _progressive enhancement_. That can be achieved –just an example– using Closure Templates used in both Java on the server-side and JavaScript (Closure Library) on the client-side. This is how Google+ is built, and I suspect GMail follows a similar pattern trying to reuse templates as much as possible (with a distinct "entry point" for the "Basic HTML" version though)